# Parallax scroll in both directions

Tags: jquery, parallax, horizontal-scrolling

I created a horizontal scroller with the help of jQuery. I now want the title under each thumbnail to have a small parallax effect in both directions. It is working but only in one direction.

I achieved this with `$(document).scrollTop()` and paste the output in the CSS via jQuery:

```
var width = $(".horizontalScroller").width() - $(window).width() + $(window).height();

$("body").css("height", width);

$(document).on("scroll", function() {

  var pixels = $(document).scrollTop();

  $(".horizontalScroller").css("left", -1 * pixels);

  $(".info").css({
    "margin-left": -0.5 * pixels
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".info").css({
      transition: "all 1s",
      "margin-left": "0",
    });
  });
});
```

You can see here what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/Dennisade/pen/BMVVMr

I want the effect to work in the opposite direction as well. I also noticed that the further I scroll, the greater the effect gets. Maybe someone has a totally different solution how to make this smooth.

I appreciate any help here.

Comment: How about this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgdgOP

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this :-)